How to identify the most important features that impact an ordinal score?
I have 40 rows of 5 continuous features and 1 ordinal score. What statistical technique is recommended for me to identify which features have the highest impact on the ordinal score? I have looked into cumulative logistic regression, but I'm not sure if I can interpret the beta coefficients as indicators of "importance" of these features, as it is about the odds of falling into or below a category?

I hope you get some better answers than this, but I would worry than with only 8 observations per predictor, any logistic regression-based model will be hopelessly under-powered. You might consider a Markov chain  ordinal model instead, but that is a topic I am only learning about myself so I can’t advise too much. Maybe @FrankHarrell could advise if he sees this.

@RobertLong I share your interest in seeing Harrell post an answer, though I think it will be the usual “bootstrap the importance ranks to discover the data unable to say, and if you’re afraid to calculate confidence intervals for the ranks, you shouldn’t be calculating them.”

I see a longitudinal analysis like a Markov ordinal model has helpful in increasing the sample size if there are several observations per experimental unit (e.g., person).
